# Does LXC support XFS filesystem?

Tags: linux, docker, lxc, xfs

I am working on my local system and I want to run both docker and LXC containers.

Docker provides storage options that only works with XFS to limit the storage volume inside containers.

But that storage limit doesn't get applied if I use BTRFS or some other FS. And now I want to run LXC containers too on the system (along with limited storage volumes). Is it possible to do so?

If yes, then how? Because currently if I convert my filesystem to XFS then I am practically not able to run LXC containers and I don't see any support online for this.

Comment: you can try to use a [File as Filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85977/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-mount-it-as-a-filesystem) for testing your purpose and uf its not working you can easily remove the Changes

Answer (score 2):

LXC is just containers; you can use any filesystem that Linux supports, subject to any restrictions imposed by that filesystem (so Windows filesystems such as NTFS would have problems). XFS will work fine.